# Изменение стандартного курсора, изменение цвета

Tags: javascript, css

Возникла задача с изменением цвета курсора при перемещении по блокам сайта. Нашлось решение, указанное в коде, mix-blend-mode:difference. Курсор плавно меняет цвет при переходе из одного блока в другой, но при этом реагирует и на наведение на текст и картинки, как исключить эти объекты для объединения mix-blend-mode?

```
 const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor')
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  cursor.setAttribute("style","top: "+(e.pageY)+"px; left: "+ (e.pageX) +"px;")
})

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target)
  cursor.classList.add('click')

  setTimeout(()=>{
    cursor.classList.remove('click')
  },500)
})

CSS:
     .cursor {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #ec5540;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      z-index: 9999;
      border-radius: 50%;
      mix-blend-mode: difference;
    }
```

Код: https://codepen.io/nstsvs/pen/GRNrEZm

Cкрин как это должно выглядеть.
[image: Пример]

[image: Пример2]

Comment: К сожалению так не получится, нужно будет скриптом прописывать для каждого фона отдельную смену цвета... Либо не юзать белые буквы) Еще можно кастыльнуть, и при наведении на текст убирать наложнеие, и просто менять цвет на нужный... Еще пара советов: у тебя твой кастомный курсор сдвинут относительно реального, нужно исправить, чтобы реальный курсор был по центру.. И еще на курсор наложи pointer-events: none; чтобы можно было ловить все события с реального курсора)